# HTML to Jinja2 how to attribute classes to form variables according to previous style

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have a bootstrap template of a login form.
I am trying to convert the HTML into jinja2 so that I can use the `LoginForm` variables of my flask application. In the `LoginForm` I define the validations, labels and further errors that I would like to display if the user input is wrong.

HTML bootstrap template

```html
<span class="bmd-form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="material-icons">email</i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
  </div>
</span>
```

[image]

Here is what I did, but the result doesn't let me edit the content of the input, however, I correctly get the data of the `form.email.label` variable.

```html
<span class="bmd-form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="material-icons">email</i>
      </span>
    </div>
    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control", type="email") }}
    {% if form.email.errors %}
      {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          {% for error in form.email.errors %}
              <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</span>
```

[image]

Any tips or hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: No, it's not that. I know how to get the placeholder. The thing is after I convert to jinja2, I can't enter data in the input fields anymore. It appears like a normal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your issue is here:

```html
{{ form.email.label(class="form-control", type="email") }}
{% if form.email.errors %}
  {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
  {% for error in form.email.errors %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

While on your simple HTML snippet, you don't have any label, in your Jinja version, you have a label **and** you put the `input` itself in the `if form.email.errors`, effectively only displaying the input when you have an error in your form.

This is just a form label, not an input:

```html
{{ form.email.label(class="form-control", type="email") }}
```

This is your actual input

```html
{{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
```

Your correct code, should rather be:

```html
{{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
{% if form.email.errors %}
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
  {% for error in form.email.errors %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

**Plase mind**, that I removed the label, as you don't have one in the design you showed as example, you have a placeholder, rather than a label.

This said, you will miss the `is-invalid` class on the filed. I would say this should work:

```html
{{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg" ~ (" is-invalid" if form.email.errors else "")) }}
{% if form.email.errors %}
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
  {% for error in form.email.errors %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! What does the tilda in the last snippet stand for?

Comment: The tilde is the [concatenation operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) in Jinja